# Label's content is being cropped in a stackview

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uistackview

I am showing two labels in a stackview as shown in the image below. I would like the first label to show its full content. For this, I tried making its horizontal content hugging priority as well as its horizontal content compression resistance priority higher than the other label. Still i am getting the cropped label as in the image. Isn't this supposed to work? How do I get the desired result? The stackview's alignment is set to 'Fill' and its distribution to 'Fill Proportionally'.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the distribution to “Fill”, not “Fill Proportionally”.